# PHP MVC - List of models?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop

I'm new to using an MVC structure, and am developing my own MVC framework for a university project. I've got a database class that I can use to send a query to the database and return me an array of objects (PHP standard object class). I then want to display a list of the objects on an index page.

My question is, should this list of standard objects really be a list of models? Or are they fine as they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create separate model classes just for the sake of creating model classes because they are in the MVC pattern name. If your solution also works when you simply pass the array of PHP standard object classes to your view, you should just use that. In that case creating model classes would just be extra work for no benefit. However, if you need additional functionality besides simply outputting a list of database results, you should consider creating actual models.

Answer (score 0):

You should store data in your database and manipulate this data (create,update,read and destroy) with your models. I think you should better know what is MVC and what is for. You can read a bit [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: Model does not directly manipulate storage. It contains other objects ( preferably [datamappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) ) which are responsible for that part. Model layer itself contains domain business logic.

Answer (score 0):

depends... One could argue that most applications are very heavy on the Model side (Fat Models is an actual pattern), therefore it will not be enough to create a few stdObjects from an array, but actually map tables to object classes, so you can add useful methods to them.

I would recommend to take a look at [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) and try implementing a subset of features.

Comment: Fat model is NOT a pattern and ORM is NOT a model.

Comment: Nope, Fat Model is a design decision and therefore a pattern. Although ORM should not be the only Model representation, they are the most atomic part.